# Difficulty running LCMM

Tags: r, do.call

I am trying to run the below code:

```
lcga1 <- lcmm::hlme(NFL_log ~ Days_since_injury, random = ~1, ng = 1, subject ='subjectId_new',  data = biom)

lcga2 <- lcmm::gridsearch(rep = 100, maxiter = 10, minit = lcga1, m=lcmm::hlme(NFL_log ~ Days_since_injury, subject ='subjectId_new', ng = 2, data = biom, mixture =~ Days_since_injury))
```

`lcag1` runs fine.

When I run `lcga2` I get this error:
`Error in do.call(as.character(mc[[1]]), as.list(mc[-1]), envir = parent.frame()) : 'what' must be a function or character string`

I can not work out what I am doing wrong to get this. Any help is appreciated. Apologies if there is not enough information - this is my first post to stack overflow.

Thank you for any help.

I have tried reinstalling R and R studio. I have also updated all packages.

Comment: Not so easy to tell without example data. Anyway: does the model you specify for the gridsearch (`lcmm::hlme(NFL_log ~ Days_since_injury, subject ='subjectId_new', ng = 2, data = biom, mixture =~ Days_since_injury)`) run OK outside the gridsearch?

Comment: Thank you for answering. When I run it outside the grid search I get this error: Error in lcmm::hlme(NFL_log ~ Days_since_injury, subject = "subjectId_new", :
B is not correct . When I try B=lcga1 or B=random(lcga1) I get this error:formal argument "B" matched by multiple actual arguments

Comment: This code runs fine: lcga2 <- gridsearch(hlme(NFL_log ~ Days_since_injury,  random =~ 1, subject = 'subjectId_new', data=biom, ng = 2, mixture=~Days_since_injury), rep=100, maxiter=30, minit=lcga1)  Thank you for answering me I_O as it helped me solve it